# how do I get kendo angular grid row index from event parameter(e)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-kendo

```
$scope.deleteClick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var datasource = $scope.mygrid.datasource;
    var index = $(e.target).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    datasource.remove(datasource.at(index -1));
}
```

At this code, you will see that I did DOM manipulation, because I did not get row index from parameter `e`. Please help me to get the row index.

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest you is to use the [removeRow](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-removeRow) method of the Grid and just pass the TR element (you cannot avoid accessing the TR element).

```
grid.removeRow($(e.target).closest('tr'))
```